# How to add new local user in Azure VM through the PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure

I have VM machine running which is not part of the domain and I would like to add the new local user through the PowerShell. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created your VM in Azure you will be able to interact with it as any other windows machine via PowerShell.

1. You will create a New-PSSession to the machine (you will use the ip adress for the VM as the computername):
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-6
2. You will then enter the session and create the local user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1

The main issue you may run into is, depending on firewall rules, you may not be able to directly access your azure VM.  You will likely need to create a VPN in azure, include your Azure VM in that VPN, and then access the VPN from your local machine before you are able to establish a connection to the Azure VM.  Please see the documentation for setting this up here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal.